# Azure AD B2C send invitation email to new user

Tags: azure-active-directory

Using the new Azure AD B2C service in preview, I am looking to be able to send a user an invitation email to complete sign-up for our SaaS application. Each of our customers will manage their own users and I want them to be able generate an invitation email to their new users for access to our SaaS application. That user would then finish the sign-up process.

Part of this process will also to be able to include what "customer" this user is assigned to. Part of the invitation process I would like to be able to identify that this customer should be a part of this customer's database in our SaaS application.

Comment: That seems like a pretty solid project, but what is your question?

Comment: My question is whether there is a process we can trigger in Azure AD B2C that will send an email invitation to the end user to finish the sign-up process instead of the end user initiating the sign-up process.

Comment: I am sure you didn't write all this just to ask a Yes/No question, which wouldn't even qualify as an answer on this site.

Comment: I am looking for a yes/no - does that possibility exist with Azure AD B2C? If so, looking for information and details on how to implement it? And further, how can I tie what "tenant" that user should have access to during this sign-up process?

Comment: Have you actually tried something? This site is for programmers to ask for assistance with their written code, it's not for people to ask for code to be written, or to ask for technical support for a 3rd party site.  see [help]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a supported feature. I recommend that you use our [User Voice forum](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory) to make feature requests; we are tracking those.

There is an existing feature request for this: [AADB2C: Send email invitation for new user to sign up](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/9874482-aadb2c-send-email-invitation-for-new-user-to-sign)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom) to achieve this.  You can send a JWT to B2C that includes the 'customer' the user is assigned to.

[There is sample code here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipGamesWebApplication/Controllers/InvitationController.cs#LC90) that sends the JWT to B2C.

The leaf policy that [receives the JWT is here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/wingtipgamesb2c/Policies/b2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com_B2C_1A_invitation.xml).

[The sample app is here](https://wingtipgamesb2c.azurewebsites.net/Invitation/Create).