# Azure Active Directory Invitation Policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2b

How to create invitation policy on Azure Active Directory and use it to send invitation to user for Business to Business (B2B) and Business to Consumer (B2C) in a web application? I use invitation API for Azure AD B2B to send invitation, but can't send when used in Azure AD B2C.

Comment: You want to invite users to a B2C directory?

Comment: Like SignUp, signIn policy I want to create invitation policy and use it in B2C directory.

Answer (score 3):

At this time, **Azure AD's B2B collaboration feature and Azure AD B2C are not compatible**. **Azure AD B2C does not have any built-in invitation mechanism** as it is tailored for self-service registration via the signup and signup/signin policies. There is an existing feedback request you can vote for: [AADB2C: Send email invitation for new user to sign up](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/9874482-aadb2c-send-email-invitation-for-new-user-to-sign).

**You can implement this yourself by creating your own invitation UI**. This UI would [call the Azure AD graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) to create the users.

You can then either:

- Use the password reset policy as their first time experience since that sends an email to the user with a code. Note that you have very limited control over the look & contents of this email.
- OR, create your own "redeeming" or "activation" mechanism, for example:

  1. Ensure you set [accountEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity) to false when creating the user.
  2. Create an activation code/link and email that to the user (using SendGrid for example). You'll need to be able to associate that code/link to the user somewhere/somehow.
  3. Once the user navigates to the link or uses the code, update the user via the Graph again to set its `accountEnabled` flag to true.

**Note:** this will only work for local users and not for social users.

Comment: Another option is the how WingTip Games demo did it, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707131/azure-ad-b2c-send-invitation-email-to-new-user#answer-46350962).

Comment: A detailed description of how it is done with the Wingtip Games demo is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984166/sign-up-policy-set-user-attributes-through-code/46996797#46996797).