# Azure AD B2C Register users after validating an Invitation Token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azureportal, email-verification

Using Azure AD B2C I create a SignUp Policy that users can use to register in my Tenant Directory.

After creating the SignUp Policy in Azure AD B2C, I get an endpoint which is used to register users. The endpoint looks like this:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=XXX&client_id=XXX&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=XXX&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login

I programatically send an email to an email address, which contains the endpoint from above and an InvitationToken. The endpoint will be opened from the email, the user will register, and at the final step he will be asked to enter the InvitationToken that he received in the email.

[image]

I want to perform a validation at this step. I want to check if the InvitationToken entered by the user is the same as the one he received in the email. If the InvitationToken he enters is invalid, I don't want the user to be able to register in my Tenant Directory.

I don't know how to perform this. I can only implement a workaround.

I store in a table the users with the InvitationToken that they received in the email and the InvitationToken that they entered at the Register step. If the 2 InvitationTokens are different, then users will not be able to use my application. But the users are still created in the Azure Portal, and they can login in the Portal.

Is there any way to make the users unable to register in my Tenant Directory if they enter an invalid InvitationToken at the register step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Send input claims to your sign-up policy.  See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707131/azure-ad-b2c-send-invitation-email-to-new-user/46350962#answer-46350962) for more details.
2. Validate the `InvitationToken` provided by the user.  See this guide: [Integrate REST API claims exchanges in your Azure AD B2C user journey as validation on user input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-rest-api-validation-custom)

---

Both options require [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom) though*.

> *Custom policies are designed primarily for identity pros who need to address complex scenarios.

---

There is an existing feature request for this: [AADB2C: Send email invitation for new user to sign up](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/9874482-aadb2c-send-email-invitation-for-new-user-to-sign)